# Replace all Occurences of '.' with '_' before '=' using sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I have a properties file as below:

```
build.number=153013
db.create.tablespace=0
db.create.user=0
db.create.schema=0
upgrade.install=1
new.install=0
configure.jboss=0
configure.jbosseap=false
configure.weblogic=1
configure.websphere=0
```

I need to import these variables into a shell script. As you know, '.' is not a valid character to use as a variable in linux. How would I use sed to replace all occurrences of '.' before the '=' with '_' . I have replaced all occurrences of '.' but there are some properties that have values which contain a '.' that I would like to not modify.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: It's nice when you show what you've tried, so others see you've tried something, and are not simply asking someone else to do your job -- which is not the case, right? :D

Comment: is there always at least one dot before the equal?

Comment: here is what i have tried : "sed 'y/./_/' $TEMP_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_MIME_TYPE/build.properties >> $TEMP_FOLDER/$FILE_NAME_WITHOUT_MIME_TYPE/build.properties.temp"

Comment: Why "using sed"? How do you know that `sed` is the right tool for the job? My first instinct would be to use native bash parameter expansion. It could also be done with awk... lots of tools that aren't sed, and so lots of possible answers that you rule out without any obvious cause.

Comment: I am not sure that it is. In my case, why would I benefit from an awk as opposed to a sed command?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
sed -e ':b; s/^\([^=]*\)*\./\1_/; tb;'
```

It replaces `stringWithoutEquals.` with `stringWithoutEquals_` for as long as the match succeeds. In effect, this replaces all the `.`'s before the `=` with `_`.

Comment: thank you for the explanation and solution! what is :b; a flag for?

Comment: @VarunPatel It's a label called `b`. `tb` means "if successful, jump to label b"

Comment: `-e` is not needed, since you one have one group of code/script

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
sed 's/\.\|\(=.*\)/_\1/g;s/_=/=/' file
```

The approach consists to capture all the content after the equal to consume all trailing characters (including possible dots). So all dots before the equal are replaced with an underscore and an empty capture group, but there is an underscore before the equal. The second replacement removes this last underscore.

Comment: thanks for the solution, would you be able to explain the logic of that statement please?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/=/&\n/;h;y/./_/;G;s/\n.*\n//' file
```

Separate the line with a marker at the `=`. Copy the line. Replace all `.`'s with `_`'s. Append the original line and subtract the text between the two markers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk -F= '{gsub(/\./,"_",$1)}1' OFS== file
build_number=153013
db_create_tablespace=0
db_create_user=0
db_create_schema=0
upgrade_install=1
new_install=0
configure_jboss=0
configure_jbosseap=false
configure_weblogic=1
configure_websphere=0
```

It divides the text by `=`, then replace in first field `.` with `_`.

Comment: what is the advantage of awk as opposed to sed?

Comment: `awk` is much more complex than `sed` and it may be more easy to read what is going on.  For simple stuff `sed` may be better.  Do a google search `sed vs awk`