# sed/awk: Replacing all occurrences of one character by another one only when preceded by a specific non blank character

Tags: json, sed, yaml

The context is to transform some structured data into JSON/YAML when some names incorrectly contain dash(es) only when they are preceded by a colon (:).

For instance, let's consider the following structured data:

```
-   name-1: value-1
    name-2:
    - value-21
    - value-22
-   name-3: value-3
    name-4:
    - value-41
    - value-42
```

The goal is to transform the former into YAML:

```
-   name_1: value-1
    name_2:
    - value-21
    - value-22
-   name_3: value-3
    name_4:
    - value-41
    - value-42
```

The trap concerns all the listed values which are not followed by a colon.

I tried the following (inspired by a [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877805/replace-all-occurences-of-with-before-using-sed)), but it incorrectly modifies the values in lists:

```
sed -E ':l; s/^([^:]*)*-([^[:blank:]]+)/\1_\2/; tl;' file
-   name_1: value-1
    name_2:
    - value_21
    - value_22
-   name_3: value-3
    name_4:
    - value_41
    - value_42
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
sed -E ':l; s/^([[:blank:]]*(-[[:blank:]]*)?[^[:space:]:-]*)-([^[:space:]:]*:)/\1_\3/; tl;' file > newfile
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/WoSeuM)

The regex works [like this](https://regex101.com/r/dIO0eQ/1):

- `^` - start of string
- `([[:blank:]]*(-[[:blank:]]*)?[^[:space:]:-]*)` - Group 1 (`\1`): 0+ horizontal whitespaces, an optional sequence of `-` and  0+ horizontal whitespaces and then 0+ chars other than whitespace, `:` and `-`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([^[:space:]:]*:)` - Group 3 (`\3`): 0 or more chars other than whitespace and `:` and then `:`

The changes are done to all `-` in the keys due to the `l` label and the `t` loop.

Comment: If we consider the other direction (YAML --> structured data meaning transforming _ --> -), how would you change the command to leave the first character of each key untouched, because it can be an underscore _ and it appears it is allowed? The following does not keep the first character of keys unchanged when it is a _ : "sed -E ':l; s/^([[:blank:]]*(-[[:blank:]]*)?(\_\*)?[^[:space:]:\_]*)\_([^[:space:]:]*:)/\1-\4/; tl;'"