# Replace all occurences of X with Y before match "xyz" using sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed

I have a list of uri's in a file:

```
https://<pattern>.hostname.com/api/<pattern>
```

Sometimes the pattern contains a underscore which is valid in the path part but not in the hostname. I wish to convert the underscores in the hostname part to hyphens, but leave the  in the path part alone. So what's wanted is: `replace '_' with '-' before "/api"` effectively.

`https://ab_c.hostname.com/api/ab_c` should become `https://ab-c.hostname.com/api/ab_c`

How to do this with `sed`? Replacing characters before matching a single character was answered here [Replace all Occurences of '.' with '_' before '=' using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26877805/replace-all-occurences-of-with-before-using-sed) , but I couldn't tweak it to do the wanted effect with a multiple character match.

Comment: A one-liner with GNU sed: `sed -E ':a; s|^([^/]*//[^/]*)_([^/]*)|\1-\2|; ta' file`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '\#/api#{s//\n&/;h;y/_/-/;G;s/\n.*\n//}' file
```

Divide and conquer or:

```
sed ':a;s#_\(.*/api.*\)#-\1#;ta' file
```

Loop until no more:

Answer (score 1):

Actually like in the previous thread I mentioned, `awk` seemed to me the most elegant:

`awk -F"/api" '{gsub(/\_/,"-",$1)}1' OFS=/api filename`

did the trick.

Thanks for your solutions anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Can be done like this in bash

```
$ url=https://ab_c.de_fhostname.com/api/ab_c
$ first=${url%/api/*}
$ last=${url#*/api/}
$ echo ${first//_/-}/api/$last
https://ab-c.de-f.hostname.com/api/ab_c
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -pe '($before) = m{(.*?/api)};
          $before =~ s/_/-/g;
          substr $_, 0, length $before, $before;
' -- file
```

- First, we extract the part up to the first `/api` to the variable $before.
- The, we replace all the underscores in $before by dashes.
- The last step takes the whole line and replaces the initial part by the new one. As the underscore has the same length as the dash, we know that we need to remove exactly the same number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Another one with `perl`

```
$ echo 'https://a_b_c_d.hostname.com/api/ab_c' | perl -pe 's|_(?=.*/api/)|-|g'
https://a-b-c-d.hostname.com/api/ab_c
```

`_(?=.*/api/)` is using positive lookahead so that `_` matches only if `/api/` occurs later in the line. Since lookarounds do not consume characters, explicit loop isn't needed.

Similar logic with `sed`

```
$ echo 'https://a_b_c_d.hostname.com/api/ab_c' | sed -E ':a s|_(.*/api/)|-\1|; ta'
https://a-b-c-d.hostname.com/api/ab_c
```

`s|_(.*/api/)|-\1|` will replace `_` with `-` only if `/api/` occurs later in the line. The loop ensures all matches are replaced.